# Scala 2.10 TypeTag usage

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I'm digging new scala reflection api and can't figure out why the following snippet doesn't work as expected. Given hierarchy (tried to simplify as much as I can):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait TF[A] {
  implicit def t: TypeTag[A]

  def f[T <: A: TypeTag]: PartialFunction[Any, A] = {
    case msg: T if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[A] => msg
  }
}

class TFilter[T: TypeTag] extends TF[T] {
  def t = typeTag[T]
}

case class Foo(x: Int)
```

I expect method `f` to filter objects of given type. So the following snippet should return `Seq[Foo]`

```
val messages = Seq(1, "hello", Foo(1))

val tFilter = new TFilter[Foo]
messages collect tFilter.f[Foo]
```

And it actually returns `Seq[Foo]` but with other messages unfiltered, which sounds like a bug.

```
res1: Seq[Foo] = List(1, hello, Foo(1))
```

**Question**. Am I using `TypeTag` wrong or it is defect of new reflection api?

**PS0**. Tried with `Scala 2.10.0-RC1` and `2.10.0-RC2`

**PS1**. The workaround is to replace `TypeTag` with `Manifest`, so with the following code `collect` on sequence will return `List(Foo(1))` as expected.

```
trait MF[A] {
  implicit def m: Manifest[A]

  def f[T <: A: Manifest]: PartialFunction[Any, A] = {
    case msg: T if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[A] => msg
  }
}

class MFilter[T: Manifest] extends MF[T] {
  def m = manifest[T]
}
```

**Update**: Same with new `Scala 2.10.0-RC2` release.

Comment: It might be helpful to add the warning you get for `case msg: T` in your code: `warning: abstract type T in type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. I don't see this warning with the old `Manifest` approach.

Comment: @som-snytt, think, it is *digging into*. Lack of english practice. I'll try to be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I think the key problem here is that you need to match against the type of `msg`, but its compile-time type is `Any` (from the `PartialFunction` declaration). Essentially, you want a different `TypeTag` for each element in your `List[Any]`. But since they all have compile-time type of `Any` by virtue of all being put into the same list, you're not going to get a `TypeTag` that's any more specific than that.

I think what you probably want to do is use `ClassTag` instead of `TypeTag`:

```
trait TF[A] {
  implicit def t: ClassTag[A]

  def f: PartialFunction[Any, A] = {
    case msg: A => msg
  }
}

class TFilter[T: ClassTag] extends TF[T] {
  def t = classTag[T]
}

case class Foo(x: Int)

val messages = Seq(1, "hello", Foo(1), List(1), List("a"))
messages collect new TFilter[Foo].f // produces List(Foo(1))
```

As [Ajran points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13234888/384641), just like the `Manifest` version, you'll have to be aware of all the limitations of runtime types including erasure and boxing issues:

```
messages collect new TFilter[List[Int]].f // produces List(List(1), List("a"))
messages collect new TFilter[Int].f // produces List()
messages collect new TFilter[java.lang.Integer].f // produces List(1)
```

There are some suggestions about how to make `TypeTag` more useful for pattern matching (e.g. [SI-6517](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6517)), but I think those will only help when you're matching against an object with an useful `TypeTag`, not an object with compile-time type of `Any`.

Comment: But due to [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag), `ClassTag` is a weaker special case of `TypeTag`, so I assume that the latter should work too.

Comment: if you look at a link in my answer you will see that is not the case: "We definitely discussed using type tags to assist pattern matching, but, I think, Adriaan has more important things to do right now."

Comment: Right, the docs say ["ClassTags are a weaker special case of scala.reflect.api.TypeTags#TypeTags, in that they wrap only the runtime class of a given type, whereas a TypeTag contains all static type information"](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag). But if your static type is `Any`, a `TypeTag` won't help you anyway, and the best you can do is the runtime class from the `ClassTag`.

Comment: @Arjan, Steve, som-snytt, thanks for your help. Think, now I understand how it works. All answers provide helpful information, but I ought to choose one.

Answer (score 2):

actually you don't check the type of msg here, compiler will warn you that msg: T is erased, so all you are left checking is that type defined on TFilter is the same as a type defined on function f.

I looks like pattern matching is "assisted" by Manifest and ClassTag, so msg: T is indeed a correct type. If you try it with primitives or List[T] it will not work correctly.

```
val mFilter = new MFilter[Int]
messages collect mFilter.f[Int] // res31: Seq[Int] = List()

val messages = List(List(1), List("a"))
val mFilter = new MFilter[List[Int]]
messages collect mFilter.f[List[Int]] // res32: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(a))
```

Look at this discussion:
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/126p8eh1w0/how-to-make-typetag-work-in-a-pattern

bug "Use TypeTags when pattern-matching otherwise erased types": [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6517)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>cm,universe=>ru}
import ru._

object Test extends App {
  type MyTag[A] = TypeTag[A]
  //type MyTag[A] = ClassTag[A]

  trait TF[A] {
    implicit def t: MyTag[A]

    def f[T <: A: MyTag]: PartialFunction[Any, A] = {
      //case msg: T => msg            // ok for ClassTag
      case msg: T @unchecked if matching[T](msg) => msg
      //case msg: T if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[A] => msg
    }
    def matching[T](a: Any)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) =
      (cm reflect a).symbol.toType weak_<:< tt.tpe
  }

  case class TFilter[A: MyTag]() extends TF[A] {
    def t = implicitly[MyTag[A]]
  }

  trait Foo { def x: Int }
  case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo
  case class Baz(x: Int) extends Foo

  val messages = Seq(1, Bar(0), "hello", Baz(1))
  println(messages collect TFilter[Foo].f[Foo])
  println(messages collect TFilter[Foo].f[Bar])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone to feedback. Think, I've found the reason why `ClassTag` should be used in pattern matching.

I've managed to find [[SI-5143] Pattern matching on abstract types doesn't work](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5143), and it's [associated commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6b3ef4f1676adcbe6dbdbf59a3bd359f339b0626) explains that there should be an instance of `ClassTag` to make pattern checkable.

So, yes, I used `TypeTag` wrong; in case of pattern matching I should use `ClassTag`.

Comment: See my updated answer - I think the real issue is that `msg` has a compile-time type of `Any`. It's not an abstract type, it a concrete type. It's just a useless concrete type. ;-)