# Scala: Using a TypeTag to match on a Some's type

Tags: scala

See the following code:

```
def createOption[T: TypeTag](referentialData: Any) : Option[T] = {
  Option(referentialData) match {
    case Some(camelMessage: CamelMessage) => {
      Option(camelMessage.body) match {
        case Some(option: T) => Some(option)
        case _ => None
      }
    }
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Basically I am looking to return an `Option[T]` if `camelMessage.body` is non-null and of type T.
The uses of `Option(referentialData)` is effectively `referentialData != null`
Likewise for `Option(camelMessage.body)`

How do I use the TypeTag to determine if `camelMessage.body` is of type T.

(I know this can be re-written to not use TypeTags and Options but I want to learn how to use TypeTags so please no suggestions to re-write, thanks!)

**Edit**

I tried a new approach as could not find a solution for the above, but could not get this one to work either:

```
def createOption[T](referentialData: Any) : Option[T] = {
  Option(referentialData) match {
    case Some(option) => Try(option.asInstanceOf[T]).toOption
    case _ => None  
  }
}
```

When I invoke this using `createOption[Long]("test")` I was presuming to get a `None` back, but instead I got a `Some(String)`
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks quite correct. It will do exactly what you want. Is there a specific problem you are faced with?

Comment: I've ran a unit test whereby I specify T as a Long and camelMessage.body is a String, and it returns a Some(String) instead of a None...so does not appear to be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826132/1296806).

But you want to try it with `ClassTag` to show the limitation:

```
scala> def f[A: ClassTag](x: Any): Option[A] = x match {
     | case y: A => println("OK"); Some(y) ; case _ => println("Nope"); None }
f: [A](x: Any)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Option[A]

scala> f[String]("foo")
OK
res0: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> f[Long](2L)
Nope
res1: Option[Long] = None

scala> f[java.lang.Long](new java.lang.Long(2L))
OK
res2: Option[Long] = Some(2)

scala> def f[A: TypeTag](x: Any): Option[A] = Option(x) match {
     | case Some(y: A) => println("OK"); Some(y) ; case _ => println("Nope"); None }
<console>:51: warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       case Some(y: A) => println("OK"); Some(y) ; case _ => println("Nope"); None }
                    ^
f: [A](x: Any)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Option[A]
```

Comment: Thanks, although not sure I understand the difference between ClassTag and TypeTag. According to the ScalaDoc the former is a partial descriptor while the latter is a full descriptor. Therefore, I thought TypeTag would also work fine