# HashMap of pseudo variables of any type nice design

Tags: scala, hashmap, type-safety

I am writing simple variable system in Scala. I need a way to nicely hold these `AnyVar`s and access them by their string names. I have this object called context to manage it but it is really just a wrapper for `HashMap[String, AnyVar]`. I want to find a nicer way to do this.

```
class Context {
  import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  private var variables = HashMap[String, AnyVal] ()

  def getVariable (name: String):AnyVal = variables(name)
  def setVariable (name: String, value: AnyVal) = variables += ((name, value))

  def getVariableOfType[T <: AnyVal : ClassTag] (name:String):T ={
    val v = variables(name)
    v match {
      case x: T => x
      case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
}
```

I really want an implementation that is type safe

Comment: Define "nicer". It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @0__ Any scala code that uses .asInstanceOf[T] is not type safe.

Comment: You can't say you want to implement accessing of `AnyVal`s using `String`s and also say you ant it to be type safe in the same sentence ;) What exactly is your larger goal here?

Comment: @VogonJeltz, in your case it is typesafe, because you already know which object is casted to `T` - `null`. There will not occur ClassCastExcception. But greater problem is that you return `null` and your code throws exceptions if the key isn't present in the map.

Comment: @LuxuryMode good point. I want to be able to store any value with a string reference. It doesn't need to be a HashMap but that is a holder solution

Comment: @ka4eli I want a way to hold these variables without using `.asInstanceOf[T]`

Comment: @VogonJeltz Same point applies. If you want "any value" then you're talking about `AnyVal` in which case you know nothing more about the object other than that is is an `AnyVal`. There's no way to refine the types further than that without resorting to `asInstanceOf` and other non-type safe methods.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining the upper bound of your variables as `AnyVal`. These are mostly primitive types such as `Int`, `Boolean` etc. not reference types for which `null` makes sense. Therefore you have to include a cast to `T`. This doesn't give you a null reference but the default value for that value type, such as `0` for `Int`, `false` for `Boolean`:

```
null.asInstanceOf[Int]      // 0
null.asInstanceOf[Boolean]  // false
```

So this has nothing to do with type-safety but just the fact that Scala would otherwise refuse to use a `null` value here. Your pattern match against `x: T` is already type-safe.

A better approach would be to return an `Option[T]` or to throw a `NoSuchElementException` if you try to query a non-existing variable or the wrong type.

Be aware that using a plain hash-map without synchronisation means your `Context` is not thread safe.

Comment: Are you saying you can call a method on `null` ?

Comment: @Dici No. Calling a method on `null` will always result in a `NullPointerException`. But there is no `null` for an `AnyVal`. In Java, an uninitialised `Int` has value `0`, an uninitialised `Boolean` is `false` etc.

Comment: `null.isIstanceOf[Int]` will produce a `NullPointerException`. I cannot test it on the device I'm using right now, but any other behaviour would suprise me

Comment: Well then let yourself be surprised :) Note that `asInstanceOf` is written as a method but translates to a cast on the JVM.

Comment: I believe you then... do you think it should be this way ? Personally, I don't, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching with abstract types is difficult, and more so with instances of `AnyVal`. I found an approach which works at [ClassTag based pattern matching fails for primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825927/classtag-based-pattern-matching-fails-for-primitives)

In general for your problem, I would simply use a `Map[String, AnyVal]` with an implicit extension to give you `getOfType`. Then you can use the existing methods to put and get variables as you wish. You can use a type alias to give your type a more meaningful reference.

```
object Context {

  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime

  type Context = Map[String, AnyVal]

  def apply(items: (String, AnyVal)*): Context = items.toMap

  implicit class ContextMethods(c: Context) {

    class MyTag[A](val t: ClassTag[A]) extends ClassTag[A] {
      override def runtimeClass = t.runtimeClass
      override def unapply(x: Any): Option[A] = 
        if (t.runtimeClass.isPrimitive && (ScalaRunTime isAnyVal x) &&
          (x.getClass getField "TYPE" get null) == t.runtimeClass)
          Some(x.asInstanceOf[A])
        else t unapply x

    }

    def getOfType[T <: AnyVal](key: String)(implicit t: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = {
      implicit val u = new MyTag(t)
      c.get(key).flatMap {
          case x: T => Some(x: T)
          case _ => None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this stuff collected together in an object which you can import, use of it becomes straightforward:

```
import Context._

val context = Context(
  "int_var" -> 123,
  "long_var" -> 456l,
  "double_var" -> 23.5d
)

context.get("int_var")//Some(123)
context.get("long_var")//Some(456)

context.getOfType[Int]("int_var")//Some(123)
context.getOfType[Double]("double_var")//Some(23.5)
context.getOfType[Int]("double_var")//None
```